# UIViewController variables initialization

Tags: ios, variables, swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I'm studying the `swift` language and I have a doubt concerning the variables initialization in a `UIViewController`. In my `DiagramViewController` I have some variables:

```
class DiagramViewController: UIViewController {

    var type: Constants.DiagramType
    var filename: String
    var numberOfBars: Int
    var numberOfSection: Int
    var diagramName: String

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Swift requires an init value for those var and I can do so in many different ways, but how should I choose between these ways?

I can init the variables "inline":

```
class DiagramViewController: UIViewController {

    var type: Constants.DiagramType = Constants.DiagramType.HISTOGRAM
    var filename: String = "dd.txt"
    var numberOfBars: Int = 10
    var numberOfSection: Int = 5
    var diagramName: String = "Diagram"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I can init the variables overriding the constructor:

```
class DiagramViewController: UIViewController {

    var type: Constants.DiagramType
    var filename: String
    var numberOfBars: Int
    var numberOfSection: Int
    var diagramName: String

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        type = Constants.DiagramType.HISTOGRAM
        filename = "dd.txt"
        numberOfBars = 10
        numberOfSection = 5
        diagramName = "Diagram"

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I can init the variables declaring them as `Optional` variables:

```
class DiagramViewController: UIViewController {

    var type: Constants.DiagramType?
    var filename: String?
    var numberOfBars: Int?
    var numberOfSection: Int?
    var diagramName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        type = Constants.DiagramType.HISTOGRAM
        filename = "dd.txt"
        numberOfBars = 10
        numberOfSection = 5
        diagramName = "Diagram"

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I can init the variables declaring them as `Implicitly Unwrapped Optional`:

```
class DiagramViewController: UIViewController {

    var type: Constants.DiagramType!
    var filename: String!
    var numberOfBars: Int!
    var numberOfSection: Int!
    var diagramName: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        type = Constants.DiagramType.HISTOGRAM
        filename = "dd.txt"
        numberOfBars = 10
        numberOfSection = 5
        diagramName = "Diagram"

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Why choose a method rather than another? Is there a typical pattern or a sort of standard concerning this issue? Maybe some of these solutions are cleaner than the others or even more efficient. Please help me understanding the difference between them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this question still waits for the best answer, which would provide details what is the recommended way of initialing variables when they are not optionals

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question could be summarized down to "When should I use optionals?". There are lots of great articles and documentation on this question, but I will attempt to put together my experience with it as well as the documentation and articles I have read.

While Optionals have very specific functionality when used, I'd like to think of them more as a way of saying something about the variable itself rather than declaring functionality. When I read:

```
var myVar:Class? = nil
```

This means, that we should never anticipate that `myVar` is assigned and instead we should always anticipate both conditions, the first being that `myVar` has a value, and that it doesn't. I assume these things because of the functionality that the `?` optional brings to the table. The compiler will not allow you to use `myVar` without unwrapping it. Because of this, the compiler suggests (whenever you access a property or function) that you use this syntax:

```
myVar?.myProperty = something
```

Because of the `?` before the `.` this line of code will **check** to see if `myVar` is `nil` before unwrapping `myVar` and executing the line of code. Thus we have anticipated and handled both conditions. This line of code will essentially be "ignored" if myVar is nil and executed if it isn't.

This is in contrast to the other type of optional `!`:

```
myVar!.myProperty = something
```

That will **always** try to unwrap `myVar`. This line of code will cause an exception saying something to the effect of: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping a value.". While the `?` will fail silently.

If we change the declaration of `myVar` to use the `!` optional:

```
var myVar:Class! = nil
```

Then we can always use `myVar` without getting the compiler error saying that we need to unwrap `myVar` prior to using it. For example, unlike the other optional (`?`), we can say:

```
myVar.myProperty = something
```

This line is equivalent to:

```
myVar!.myProperty = something
```

So if `myVar` is `nil`, then we will crash the program.

### Conclusion:

Using either one of these optionals (or simply not using an optional at all) we are telling the user of `myVar` things about `myVar` because of the way the language will force or not force you to deal with `myVar`.

#### `?` optional `var myVar:Class? = nil`:

If I use the `?` optional, we're essentially forcing the user to always check for `nil`.

#### `!` optional `var myVar:Class! = nil`:

If we use `!` then if `myVar` is nil, something is wrong and we should crash the program, however, the user still has the option to handle the `nil` case which is especially useful if the user is the one whom was supposed to assign `myVar`. A great use case of this is network requests.

#### no optional `var myVar = Class()`:

Not using an optional at all means (obviously) that the variable is **always** there and we don't ever need to worry that it is `nil`.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

The way I now deal with this was taught to me by a fellow dev, and involves using Xcode's way of dealing with this when they know a value will always be set:

For outlets you will see instance variables (as outlets) written like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var twoPlayerButton: UIButton!
```

So if you can instantiate the class in the instance variable declaration line, then I would:

```
private var myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
```

If you cannot setup MyClass() in the instance variable line (e.g. because its constructor requires other variables to be passed in) then I would set the instance variable similar to how xcode deals with Outlets e.g.:

```
private var myClass: MyClass!
```

And then instantiate it in the viewDidLoad() method

If, however, I am not setting the value early on and/or it may get set back to nil, then I would declare it as an optional and require that anyone editing code within my class unwraps it appropriately.